# Index Epubs Windows

Tags: windows-7, search

Is there any way to get Windows to index epub and mobi files so that I can search them?

After reading [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/in-windows-7-i-want-to-search-for-all-files/aadfe1f1-4a33-406b-8e72-bb920efa4f30), I was able to add epubs to the list of indexed files, but it only gives me plain text as an option.

Unfortunately both epub and mobi are not plain text files so the even if Windows indexes them searching will be thrown off because they are filled without a lot of funky characters.

Answer (score 5):

File types not recognised by default by the **Windows Indexing Service** and **Windows Search** require an [**IFilter**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFilter) to allow for indexing and full text searches. You can see a list of all installed IFilters using [**IFilter Explorer**](https://web.archive.org/web/20130907074050/http://www.citeknet.com/Products/IFilters/IFilterExplorer/tabid/62/Default.aspx):

[image: 1]

You can also use Nirsoft's [**SearchFilterView**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/search_filter_view.html) for this purpose (it also allows you to add/remove extensions to/from an installed filter):

[image: 2]

Unfortunately, having searched all the IFilter provider sites listed in that Wikipedia article and others I know of or found on the net, I was unable to find any for the EPUB and MOBI formats.

Unless someone finds a link I missed, I think your options are:

- [Develop your own IFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965717%28VS.85%29.aspx) if you are a programmer or know one
- Request [IFilterShop](http://www.ifiltershop.com), [Citeknet](http://www.citeknet.com) or other IFilter developers to do the needful (possibly for a fee, ask them for details)
- Use another app such as perhaps an eBook reader with indexing/library support to perform your searches

Comment: It appears your application is gone.  Here is a link to the 32 bit versions http://www.ghacks.net/2009/08/16/windows-ifilter-explorer/

Comment: It appears neither run on 64bit w7 and above.  Do you now of a fix?  I'm thinking about adding a bounty.

Comment: @William: See if my edit above helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: get Windows to index epub (.epub) files.

After reading this, I was able to add epubs (.epub) to the list of indexed files.

1 - download [Nirsoft's SearchFilterView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/search_filter_view.html).

2 - open SearchFilterView.

3 - in SearchFilterView, search and click on offfiltx.dll (zip filter):

4- clink on menu "file" -> "add extensions to filter":

[image: screenshot1]

5 - close the SearchFilterView;

6 - done:

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Download Nirsoft's SearchFilterView: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/search_filter_view.html

Comment: This won't work. You need an iFilter as well to actually search the files. See the accepted answer.