# How can I change the default filter Windows is using for indexing file contents?

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

In windows every file type is indexed using specific filters. Windows give an oportunity to change between two options for each file type in Indexing Options > Advanced > File Types:

- Index Properties Only
- Index Properties and File Contents

If the second option is selected every file type has certain filter that is default but I can't find how to change this filter without going into registry?

For example `.html` files have associated HTML Filter, problem is that this filter does not search everything inside html file as described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309173):

> Filter components may ignore some text because of the format or content of the text. For example, the HTML 3.0 filter (Nlhtml.dll) ignores text that is contained in comments in an HTML file (for example, a file with an .htm or .asp extension) because the text is not displayed when you open the file in a browser.

That being said default filter for `.html` files can be changed to Plain text filter by changing `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.html\PersistentHandler\(Default)` value to `{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}` which is Plain text filter persistent handler that can be found in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}\(Default) = Plain Text persistent handler`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PreviewConfig](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/previewconfig-tool-registers-file-types-for-the-preview-pane-in-windows-vista/) to easily change the preview handler for a specific file type without needing to wade through the registry:

[image: 1]

Comment: Related answer about [IFilters](http://superuser.com/a/561873/138343).